# Sharepoint 2013 style library document not accessible with read permission

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a .css file and 2 .js files in a subfolder in my style library (these files are being referred in my master page). 
Users who have read permission (visitor group) are not able to access those files (files are not even visible in folder for that user).
When I give edit permission to that group, user is able to access the file. 
I don't want to give edit permission to the user.

Please suggest what I can do to allow user to view or download these files.

Comment: Your question is a good one. May I suggest you another site in the Stack Exchange, though? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com. It is just like this one, but 100% Sharepoint oriented.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with "Read" access to the "Style Library" but to do with the Publishing features. These files will be accessible in read mode once you publish a major version of the .js and css files.